# Apache mod_rewrite not working for HTTPS with www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have two domain names: example.com and example.us and want to redirect all of them to just one.

And I want

```
http://example.us,
https://example.us,
http://www.example.us
https://www.example.us,
http://example.com,
http://www.example.com,
https://www.example.com
```

to redirect to https://example.com

On the apache conf files(httpd.conf and ssl.conf) I wrote:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.us
     RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
     RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</Directory>
```

My root directory is /var/www/html

The problem is that all of them but one works.

https://www.example.us keeps the same url and throws an ssl error (because my certificate is for example.com and not example.us). I need it to redirect to https://example.com too.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.example.us keeps the same url and throws an ssl error (because my certificate is for example.com and not example.us). I need it to redirect to https://example.com too.

Since redirection is done only after the SSL handshake the certificate needs to be valid for the domain you redirect from. That means that when connecting to www.example.us the server needs to provide a certificate which covers www.example.us, even if you only want to use this connection to redirect away from this domain to example.com.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I installed a self-signed certificate just to test. https://example.us works correctly (redirecting to https://example.com). https://www.example.us shows the page correctly (it shows the ssl warning and I accept to continue to the page anyway) but it doesn't get redirected to the correct domain.
I think something is happening just for the subdomain www with the HTTPS protocol, but I don't know what